# Render complex a tag with link_to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<a class="lightbox-trigger" data-lightbox="gallery" href="large.jpg"
title="A large image" coords="Right here">
    <%= image_tag("large.jpg", alt: "pass", width: "220", height: "147")%>
        <p> Jackie Smith
        <br />
        Won 5 October 2013
        </p>
</a>
```

Right, I've got this horrible mess of html and erb (that does work!), but I want to do things properly and render the whole thing with the `link_to` method. But I'm not sure how to do this, I can only render text with the link_to at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% link_to "large.jpg", class: 'lightbox-trigger', data: {lightbox: :gallery}, title: 'A large image', coords: 'Right here' do %>
    <%= image_tag("large.jpg", alt: "pass", width: "220", height: "147")%>
        <p> Jackie Smith
        <br />
        Won 5 October 2013
        </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you reckon this would better with the `content` method?

Comment: Yes I think is cleaner.